# How to disable all click events expects some div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable click from each element except some of them like  Button, Anchor, input, select, `.nav-class` and checkbox, the mentioned elements should be clickable. I don't want any other element to be clickable, so I write following jQuery code but it is not working.

CODE:-

```
$('html').click(function() {
   $('a , input , button , select ,.boxy-checkbok-box ').click(function(event){
      return true;
   });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try use [.not() filtering](http://api.jquery.com/not/) (jQuery)

```
 $('a , input , button , select ,.boxy-checkbok-box').not('.your-selectors, .another-one').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**html**

`<p class="love">love</p>
<a href="#">a</a><br>
<input type="text" value="input"><br>
<button>button</button><br>
<select value="select"></select><br>
<span class="boxy-checkbok-box ">boxy-checkbok-box </span>`

**script**

`$(document).on('click', 'a , input , button , select ,.boxy-checkbok-box ', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});`

love div or other element not declared in the on click event is disabled for clicking